# I want to open a new html when the screen size is below "width 700" automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I never used JavaScript before and i need some help.

I used the script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (screen.width <= 700) {
    window.location = "mobile.html";
  }
</script>
```

but it does not work.

Comment: In what way does "it not work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs once the page is loaded, if the window is resized the code doesn't recognise that fact. Use eventListeners:

```
window.onload=a;
window.onresize=a;
function a(){
  if(window.innerWidth<700){
  window.loaction="mobile.html";
}}
```

Comment: @tyrantel: thanks for giving an upvote, but please mark it as an answer to tell others that this question was answered

Answer (score 1):

Use this function in JS, and call it in HTML on resize as given below:

HTML:

```
<body onresize="openHtml()" onload="openHtml()">
```

--"onresize" attribute calls the function when the window is resized.

--"onload" attribute calls the function when the window is loaded for the first time.

JS:

```
<script>
     function openHtml()
     {
         if(window.innerWidth <= 700) {
             window.location.href = "mobile.html";
         }
     }
</script>
```